# Refactor DAX code that utilises SUMX and SUMMARIZE

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a DAX code that I know can be hugely improved on in terms of efficiency and performance but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

```
Total GMRR (EUR) =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE (
            fact_transaction_monthly,
            dim_partner[partner_created_date],
            dim_partner[partner_name],
            "GMRR", SUM ( fact_transaction_monthly[euroConsolidatedGMRR] ),
            "check", [checkActive]
        ),
        [check] = 1
    ),
    [GMRR]
)
```

I am creating a summary table and summing over the values where the check is equal to 1 but this is taking a long time to compute

Check Active Code:

```
checkActive = 
    IF ([Total Active Partners] = 1,1,0)
```

Comment: can you add [checkActive] code?

Comment: Did you try a pair AddColumns/Summarize ? it can work faster.

Comment: You can try to filter `fact_transaction_monthly`

Comment: @Mik The checkactive code has been added, and not sure how I can filter it and get the correct answer because I need every row apart from the ones which are not active reason why I filter after the summary table, however `SUMX` is obviously an iterator function and summarize will loop over the virtual table to check whether it's active. I am trying to use `SUM` and `CALCULATETABLE` instead of `SUMX`, however I can't get it to work

Comment: CALCULATETABLE , FILTER, CALCULATE these functions are very heavy. You wont earn any value by replacing FILTER with CALCULATETABLE. What you can try is 1 - check Addcolumns/Summarize pair instead of summarize  like `ADDCOLUMNS(SUMMARIZE (           fact_transaction_monthly, dim_partner[partner_created_date] ,dim_partner[partner_name]),  "GMRR", CALCULATE(SUM ( fact_transaction_monthly[euroConsolidatedGMRR] )),"check", [checkActive])`  in some cases it can work faster, but check the syntax It can be that some comma was lost.

Comment: 2- try to reduce `fact_transaction_monthly` . Most probably you are correct, but for me it's not obvious - I don't have the "puzzle" ) . It would be nice to see[Total Active Partners] code as well.

Comment: 3 - add calculated column for filtering.

Comment: 4 - reassemble `Summarize()` may be you can use another base table - smaller then `fact_transaction_monthly`.

Comment: but first check option - 1 :)

Comment: using `ADDCOLUMNS with SUMMARIZE` I would still need to perform a SUMX over that table though along with filtering it where the check is = 1, I tried it and its literally only like a couple milliseconds faster, still takes like 13 seconds to render

Comment: you can think about usage of except() function with summarized table. It's hard to advice a solution due to not simple data model.

Answer (score 0):

```
Total GMRR (EUR) =
SUMX (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SUMMARIZE (
            fact_transaction_monthly,
            dim_partner[partner_created_date],
            dim_partner[partner_name],
            "GMRR", SUM ( fact_transaction_monthly[euroConsolidatedGMRR] )
        ),
        [checkActive] = 1
    ),
    [GMRR]
)
```

Comment: It says `placeholder has been used in a True/False expression. This is not allowed.`